# Istio routing ports specification

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress, istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to switch from an `nginx` Ingress to using `Istio` to take advantage of route weights for canary deployments, and integrated monitoring, among other things.

My regular routing was defined as:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: solar-demo
  annotations:
    nginx.org/server-snippet: "proxy_ssl_verify off;"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: shmukler.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /city/*
        backend:
          serviceName: solar-demo
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /solar/*
        backend:
          serviceName: solar-demo
          servicePort: 3001
--
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: solar-demo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: city
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  - name: solar
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
  selector:
    app: solar-demo
```

I don't even need `auth`, right now. When I started `install/kubernetes/istio-demo.yaml`, it created a bunch of pods and services in the `istio-system` namespace.

I figured, possibly incorrectly, that I need to have a `VirtualService` and maybe route rules defined. Wrote:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: solar-demo
spec:
  hosts:
    - shmukler.example.com
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: shmukler.example.com
        subset: blue
      weight: 90
    - destination:
        host: shmukler.example.com
        subset: green
      weight: 10
```

Are ports defined in the regular service, while weights and paths in a `VirtualService`? Do I need to stick anything into the `istio-system` namespace? Is it possible, and what would I need to extend `istio-demo.yaml` to do the routing, I need, just to get the things rolling?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Gateway and a VirtualService.

Check out [this task](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/) for an example.